# Install and configure weblogic server on CentOS 6.3

Tags: oracle, centos, weblogic, java

I need to install and configure an Oracle Weblogic server on CentOS 6.3.
I have read that I need to install the appropiate version of JDK.

Actually I'm too inexperienced and I have searched a lot for a good tutorial, but I have no found any helpful result.

I will be so grateful to receive your help.

The complete version of CentOS I have is:

**Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-279.el6.i686 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 10:59:55 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux**

By the way, I would like to know if this is a 32 bits or 64 bits version.

PDT: Sorry for my bad english, I hope I'm making myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your machine seems to have a 32bit processor:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-find-if-processor-is-64-bit-or-not/

You can download the 32 bit version of WebLogic from here: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-for-dev-1703574.html

The 32bit version for Linux already contains the JDK and runs also on 64bit machines.

To install with 64bit you have to download and install the 64bit JDK separately and then install with the "Generic" jar installer.